# Как вынести эту логику в отдельный метод

Tags: java

```
for(MusicBand band : musicBands) {
            if (band.getYear() > 2000) {
                groupsAfter2000.add(band);
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println(groupsAfter2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вы работаете в Intellij IDEA, то вы можете выделить код, который хотите вынести в отдельный метод, далее нажать комбинацию <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.

Либо вы можете выделить код, нажать на правую кнопку мыши, выбрать пункт **Refactor**, далее выбрать пункт [**Extract Method**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/extract-method.html).

Но если вы все-таки хотите написать код сами, то метод в Java пишется следующим образом:

```java
private void myMethod() {
    // ваш код
}
```

В скобках перечислите параметры, которые вы хотите чтобы были у метода. А вместо `void` можете написать возвращаемый тип.

В самом простом случае метод будет принимать коллекцию `musicBands` и распечатывать отфильтрованные музыкальные группы на экран:

```java
private void printGroupsAfter2000(Collection<MusicBand> musicBands) {
    List<MusicBand> groupsAfter2000 = new ArrayList<>();
    for (MusicBand band : musicBands) {
        if (band.getYear() > 2000) {
            groupsAfter2000.add(band);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(groupsAfter2000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я полагаю, у Вас

- необходимо отфильтровать список групп, которые были основаны после 2000-го года.
- переменную `groupsAfter2000` скорее всего вы создали аккурат перед указанным куском кода и ее создание можно перенести внутрь метода
- результатом работы данного метода должен являться - список отфильтрованных групп, т.е. `groupsAfter2000`
- единственным параметром данного метода будет являться список групп, которые нужно отфильтровать

итого сигнатура данного метода должна выглядеть следующим образом:

```
public List<MusicBand> filterBandsFormedAfter2000(List<MusicBand> musicBands) {
    //...
}
```

Итого метод будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
public List<MusicBand> filterBandsFormedAfter2000(List<MusicBand> musicBands) {
    List<MusicBand> groupsAfter2000 = new ArrayList<>();

    for(MusicBand band : musicBands) {
        if (band.getYear() > 2000) {
            groupsAfter2000.add(band);
        }
    }

    return groupsAfter2000;
}
```

также можно в параметры вынести год, чтобы не ограничиваться одним 2000-м:

```
public List<MusicBand> filterBandsFormedAfter(List<MusicBand> musicBands, int year) {
    List<MusicBand> groups = new ArrayList<>();

    for(MusicBand band : musicBands) {
        if (band.getYear() > year) {
            groups.add(band);
        }
    }

    return groups;
}
```

Стоит отметить, что если эти методы появлялись в процессе жизни приложения и если они сосуществуют в приложении одновременно стоит произвести рефакторинг и избавиться от дублирующегося кода в данных методах.

В данном случае реализацию `filterBandsFormedAfter2000(List<MusicBand> musicBands)` можно(и нужно) свести к вызову более универсального метода `filterBandsFormedAfter(List<MusicBand> musicBands, int year)`

```
public List<MusicBand> filterBandsFormedAfter2000(List<MusicBand> musicBands) {
    return filterBandsFormedAfter(musicBands, 2000);
}
```

И использование:

```
List<MusicBand> musicBandsAfter2000 = filterBandsFormedAfter2000(musicBands);
List<MusicBand> musicBandsAfter2005 = filterBandsFormedAfter(musicBands, 2005);

System.out.println(musicBandsAfter2000); 
System.out.println(musicBandsAfter2005);
```

#### Streams

Также стоит помнить, что с появлением стримов в Java, такие операции как фильтрация стали гораздо лаконичнее

```
List<MusicBand> bandsAfter2000 = bands.stream().filter((band) -> band.getYear() > 2000 ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Что здесь происходит?

Сначала мы определяем stream на основе нашего списка

```
bands.stream()
```

Сообщаем нашему потоку, что мы хотим его отфильтровать

```
.filter( /*...*/ )
```

И передаём в него лямбду, которая будет являться условием фильтрации данного потока

```
(band) -> band.getYear() > 2000
```

В нашем случае мы принимаем на вход параметр `band`, являющийся музыкальной группой и пропускаем все группы, у которых верно данное выражение `band.getYear() > 2000`

После чего мы обратно приводим поток к списку

```
.collect(Collectors.toList())
```

И сохраняем результат фильтрации в переменную

```
List<MusicBand> bandsAfter2000 = //...
```

Последние пару пунктов, кстати необязательны, потому что при необходимости мы можем обработать элементы данного потока с помощью `forEach`

Например, вывести все элементы потока можно так:

```
.forEach(System.out::println)
```

Что-то более сложное, можно сделать с помощью лямбды

```
.forEach(band -> { band.setSomething(calculateSomething); })
```

---

**PS:** *Спасибо* @NowhereMan *за дельные замечания.*

Comment: @NowhereMan , как и обещал: внес все изменения по всем пунктам.